# Is Metro Framework NuGet Package free or not?

Tags: .net, winforms, metroframework

I saw the metro framework on the nuget packages which provides me a lot better UI for winforms application, so I want to use that framework in my winforms application, but I am not sure about its licensing. I read about its license in the "View License" option and it reads out to be "free of charge", but on the other hand metro framework is actually a paid framework (I assume).

So I am confused whether I should use the framework in my application or not, as I am not able to decide on the kind of license it has.

Help would be appreciated.

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of 
>   this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal in the 
>   Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights to use, copy, 
>   modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, 
>   and to permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to the 
>   following conditions:
>
> The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in 
>   all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
>
> (https://github.com/thielj/MetroFramework/blob/master/LICENSE.md)

As you read the last line of the licensing agreement it states you can use the framework and distribute the same provided you add the notice in your application.